# internal and external link for books web application

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce

I am developing a web book application using the PHP framework CodeIgniter. Users will be able to add books, their chapters and the pages in each chapter. Page contents will be HTML, with internal and external links.

How can I add the internal link of a page from any internal book, where the page will be in a table with the book and chapter number reference? I may need to add links from the same book and from other books from same application. I may need to add a link for an external site as well.

I am using tinymce as page editor.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to answer your question without more details. It sounds like you want to add your links as separate fields and not rely on tinyMCE to do everything you want it to do. Codeigniter can do this easily but you have to understand how to program that in general, which is more of a basic knowledge in php and database architecture problem than anything. Maybe you can update your post with what you have tried and maybe your controller / model structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you want to do it:

Setup your urls as you want:  www.yourbooksite.com/book/id/pageid or /book/id#pageid

You can also use Codeigniters url functions and do something like:  www.yourbooksite.com/book/book_name/page_number or /book/book_name#page_number.

If you have all the pages compiled on the same page, then use page anchors (`#page_id` or `#page_num`).  You can use that on external sites as well, and the document will scroll to that section of the page.

If they pages are displayed on their own pages, then just use the page_id or the page_number as another parameter you are passing.

This is an easy topic and purely preference.  I can't give code, and I can't help fix code that you are not showing.  I can get more specific, but your question is lacking, so ultimately, I can't give you a definite answer of how to do something.

Comment: www.yourbooksite.com/book/book_id/chapter/chapter_id/page/page_id this convention may help. Now can you please give one more hint to tackle the link clicking. If it has to open in browser it will be simple but if I want to open some jquery popup how it will be possible.